# qml dynamic binding to parent.width

Tags: qt, qml

For my qml project I have a button that switches the view of an element.
A function is called to change the width/height

```
function toggleView()
{
    if( pageSavedFiles.listViewToggle == true)
    {
        pageSavedFiles.cellWidth = parent.width;
        pageSavedFiles.loaderWidth = parent.width
        pageSavedFiles.cellHeight = 50
        imageViewMode.source = "design/List view.png"
        pageSavedFiles.listViewToggle= false
    }
    else
    {
        pageSavedFiles.loaderWidth = 150
        pageSavedFiles.cellWidth = 170
        pageSavedFiles.cellHeight = 170
        imageViewMode.source = "design/Grid view.png"
        pageSavedFiles.listViewToggle= true
    }
}
```

The problem is that after resizing the width is not adjusted when using parent.width. My guess is that it is only set once and after resizing not calculated again.
How can I bind it to parent.width so that it is continiously equal to the parent.width and not set only one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a binding in a piece of Javascript, you need to do the following:

```
pageSavedFiles.cellWidth = Qt.binding(function() { return parent.width; } )
```